# NoSuchMethodError : Class 'Text' has no instance method 'split' in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am fetching the text data from API call and the output is `18:00` from API call, then I try to split the output data that is '18' in one variable and `00` in another variable. After that I pass this two variable in print object and then run the code, It shows:

```
NoSuchMethodError : Class 'Text' has no instance method 'split' receiver: Instance of 'Text' Tried calling : split (":").
```

Below is the code hope you can understand what i mean.

```dart
        class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
        }

        class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
          static var api;
          List<String> dataList2;
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        Column(
    children:widget[
        api=Text(item[pos].asr), //the Text widget which has data are from api call
        dataList2 = api.split(':'),
        print(dataList2);
    ]
    )
        ) 
        }}
```

Comment: You should use `split` on a string like `18:00` no tfor a widget like `Text'.

Comment: @NoobN3rd Could you please write the code because i don't understand the split on a string.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is like this(I didn't do your example, my code is another sample).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ClassName extends StatefulWidget {
  ClassName({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ClassNameState createState() => _ClassNameState();
}

class _ClassNameState extends State<ClassName> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('18:00'.split(':')[0]),
            Text('18:00'.split(':')[1]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And to work with API You should do some other stuff, You can find good examples here or on [Medium](https://medium.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` widget does not create a string. All the `Text` widget does is make a string displayable in a UI.

To split a string, use the `String.split()` method.

```
String hi = "Hello, I'm a string!";
String newHi = hi.split(' '); // will split a string by ' ' and return a list that will be ["Hello,", "I'm", "a", "string!"]
```

What you should do:

```
var string = item[pos].asr.split(':');
Text(string) // creates new displayable text with new string
```

Good luck!

Comment: No, it is not working if i write var string=item[pos].asr.split(':'); then it is showing red line error "the element type List<String> can't be assigned to the list type Widget"

Comment: Ah, the split method returns a list. You should look through the list and add it to a new string and set it to that.

Answer (score 0):

you can split `string` not `widget` ,and split returns `List<>`

```
String text = "18:00";
List<String> splittexts = text.split(":");
```

and output would be:

```
splittexts[0] == "18"
splittexts[1] == "00"
```